# Is my IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL Bugcheck Firefox's fault, or Flash Player's fault?

Tags: firefox, graphics-card, bsod, minidumps

I hope this is the right place to post this. It seems that whenever I watch videos online in Firefox, I get a BSOD. It's a `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` BSOD. I ran `windbg` to analyze by minidump in verbose mode and this is what it gave me.

The lines I am concerned about are:

```
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xA

PROCESS_NAME:  firefox.exe
```

It seems that the Bugcheck was initiated by Firefox. But, the site uses Flash to show the video. Is it Firefox's fault, or Flash? Or could it be faulty memory? In the stack trace, there appear to be some graphics related function calls like `NtGdiCreateCompatibleBitmap`. Does this mean anything? Thank you so much for your help.

And this is the entire result from `windbg`:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.11.0001.404 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


{blah, blah, blah, loading symbols, etc.}
...............................................................
................................................................
.............................................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
..........
ERROR: FindPlugIns 8007007b
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck A, {805d7000, 0, 1, 82c8bd8e}

Probably caused by : win32k.sys ( win32k!PALLOCMEM+29 )

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> !analyze -v
ERROR: FindPlugIns 8007007b
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 805d7000, memory referenced
Arg2: 00000000, IRQL
Arg3: 00000001, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: 82c8bd8e, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


WRITE_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from 82db6718
Unable to read MiSystemVaType memory at 82d96160
 805d7000 

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!KiXMMIZeroPagesNoSave+6
82c8bd8e 0f2b01          movntps xmmword ptr [ecx],xmm0

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xA

PROCESS_NAME:  firefox.exe

TRAP_FRAME:  c8223b1c -- (.trap 0xffffffffc8223b1c)
ErrCode = 00000002
eax=00000000 ebx=001fdac8 ecx=000096b2 edx=00000000 esi=fb402000 edi=fb5da000
eip=82c8ce85 esp=c8223b90 ebp=c8223ba8 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0008  ss=0010  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0030  gs=0000             efl=00010206
nt!memset+0x45:
82c8ce85 f3ab            rep stos dword ptr es:[edi]
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 82c8bd8e to 82c9482b

STACK_TEXT:  
c8223908 82c8bd8e badb0d00 00000040 c8223928 nt!KiTrap0E+0x2cf
c82239a0 82d00ca3 00000000 d4e10c80 00000002 nt!KiXMMIZeroPagesNoSave+0x6
c82239b8 82cdc92c 00000000 fb5da000 c07daed0 nt!MiZeroPhysicalPage+0xa4
c82239f8 82cde999 00000001 fb5da000 c8223b1c nt!MiResolveDemandZeroFault+0x158
c8223a78 82cd4d76 fb5da000 00000000 8e6a2d70 nt!MiDispatchFault+0x659
c8223b04 82c94638 00000001 fb5da000 00000000 nt!MmAccessFault+0x157c
c8223b04 82c8ce85 00000001 fb5da000 00000000 nt!KiTrap0E+0xdc
c8223b90 9c659d18 fb402000 00000000 001fdac8 nt!memset+0x45
c8223ba8 9c66dbae 001fdac8 35316847 c8223c58 win32k!PALLOCMEM+0x29
c8223bc4 9c6830bf 001fdac8 00000005 00000001 win32k!AllocateObject+0x98
c8223c24 9c657b57 00000f04 00000000 00000000 win32k!SURFMEM::bCreateDIB+0x261
c8223c90 9c657661 00000000 00000006 01080030 win32k!hsurfCreateCompatibleSurface+0x2a8
c8223d0c 9c6576f3 ffb92748 000003c1 0000021f win32k!GreCreateCompatibleBitmap+0x1cd
c8223d20 82c9144a 24012070 000003c1 0000021f win32k!NtGdiCreateCompatibleBitmap+0x19
c8223d20 776f64f4 24012070 000003c1 0000021f nt!KiFastCallEntry+0x12a
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
0031edbc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0x776f64f4


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
win32k!PALLOCMEM+29
9c659d18 83c40c          add     esp,0Ch

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  8

SYMBOL_NAME:  win32k!PALLOCMEM+29

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: win32k

IMAGE_NAME:  win32k.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4c1c425a

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xA_win32k!PALLOCMEM+29

BUCKET_ID:  0xA_win32k!PALLOCMEM+29

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> .trap 0xffffffffc8223b1c
ErrCode = 00000002
eax=00000000 ebx=001fdac8 ecx=000096b2 edx=00000000 esi=fb402000 edi=fb5da000
eip=82c8ce85 esp=c8223b90 ebp=c8223ba8 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0008  ss=0010  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0030  gs=0000             efl=00010206
nt!memset+0x45:
82c8ce85 f3ab            rep stos dword ptr es:[edi]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that it's some sort of incompatibility between Flash and your graphics card driver, as applications themselves cannot cause BSoDs. Try updating your graphics drivers and Flash. You might want to try BlueScreenView as well.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. From the looks of things, can I rule out RAM issues?

Comment: @SimpleCoder: It's certainly possible that you have RAM issues, but unlikely, as it keeps failing at the same location. It's still worth running [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) a few passes (preferably overnight) to be sure.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that soon. Before I do that, though, I think I will try watching the same videos in Chrome and IE, to see if it is a problem unique to Firefox.

Comment: @Hello71 What is the reason that applications themselves cannot cause BSODS ? I once read that BSODs can occur if a app-A writes to app-B's memory location, and computer will BSOD when app-B reads the memory (which is corrupted).

Comment: @Pacerier: For one, it is usually not permitted to write to another process's memory. Where it is, it is impossible for that process to cause a BSoD for the same reason that the first one can't. It's kinda like trying to halt the system by writing a file. Sure, you can write to your home directory, but that doesn't crash the system. You have no permissions to write to any system directory.

Comment: @Hello71 I don't get it.. does it mean that applications written with C++ are incapable of causing BSODs?

Comment: @Pacerier **All** usermode apps are incapable of direcly crashing the system. It’s always a driver’s fault.

Comment: @kinokijuf isn't it true that alot of apps aren't usermode? stuff like anti-virus apps etc aren't exactly *usermode* apps are they?

Comment: @Pacerier They are _drivers_, not apps.

Comment: @kinokijuf If we download a .exe file, how do we tell if its an app or a driver?

Comment: @Pacerier It’s always an app. However it may install a driver if ran with admin priveleges.

Comment: @kinokijuf Ic, so is it true to say that any .exe file which I run with admin priveleges has the ability to BSOD my computer if they so desire?

Comment: @Pacerier Anything you run with admin privileges has, well, the privileges of an admin. Which include such things as crashing the system.

Comment: @Pacerier: Special code needs to be run to cause a BSoD. Look up kernel mode on Wikipedia.